# Drupal 7: HTML in site name shows in page title

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7, title

I'm using a subtheme of Bartik in Drupal 7. When I set the site name in configuration/site imformation, I used a few span tags. It works fine where the site name is displayed in the header, but the page title in the browser shows the HTML code when it displays the site name. I looked at Drupal documentation and it said:

> "Beware: $title is interpreted as HTML. If you have plaintext strings such as for example $node->title, you must escape them with check_plain or use the correct placeholder in t()>before passing them to drupal_set_title(). If you don't, users can execute a cross site scripting attack against your site."

That confused me more because it says the title is interpreted as HTML. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML-formatted strings for such key things as page title is a bad idea for any CMS on any number of fronts: security, indexing/SEO, database integrity, content integrity and separation of content and presentation. Drupal is scrupulous on cleansing its strings, so you've hit your head where previous heads have been burned.

This is purely a presentation issue, just use jquery or similar to achieve the same affect for your users. By the way, this will allow you greater flexibility to repurpose this content elsewhere in ways you or you client haven't specified yet.

Comment: Thanks, you make a lot of good points I had not even thought about. I know a little javascript but no jquery. I'm good at researching this stuff though so I will start looking into it. Any other comments or tips to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: so I can figure out how to write the javascript function to do what i want to the site name. I will include the .js file in my subtheme.info file. Can you tell me how I would implement the function though without doing it through the gui? Thanks

Comment: I'd be happy to help set you up with the default script.js that I use for my sites, but I'll need some time. Feel free to contact me at my email listed on my profile page if you wish in the meantime.

Comment: Heh, I was typing up my response, when while researching my answer, found [this page](http://drupal.org/node/171213&) that does a much better job than I on how to do this. That should orient you on your next steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you've saved me a lot of time and trial & error. Though I'm sure it will still take a lot of both.